# VS2010: ToolStripContainer with Washed Out StatusStrip on Bottom (Win7, Winform)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, transparency

I have a Windows Form designed with Visual Studio 2010.

It has a `ToolStripContainer` with a `StatusStrip` control placed on the bottom.

From the Visual Studio IDE's Designer, the control looks fine:

[image: Designer View]

When I run the application, the `StatusStrip` object on the bottom becomes transparent/opaque, and is very hard to read. This project is only about 2 weeks old, and I have not done anything to monkey with the transparency or opacity of any of the controls.

What could be causing this? How would I debug it?

[image: Running View]

**EDIT:**

So, I did a search on my *Current Project* on the control's name (*statusStrip1*). Unfortunately, there is very little information. I also ran a search on the `ToolStripContainer`, but it had roughly the same information - nothing that should cause the display to be transparent. The `StatusStrip` search result is shown below:

[image: Find Results]

Comment: If you resize the window does the text clear up at certain sizes?

Comment: No, but I *can* move the control (window) over something dark and the contrast is better.

Comment: Just ensure that you haven't set the enabled property to "false" for either the status strip or the labels.

Comment: Everything is enabled, Raghu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You won't believe this.

I stopped this problem by setting the *WinForm*'s `TransparencyKey` to **Fushsia** (it was set on **Transparent**).